# How do I or "die" in an "if"?

Tags: php, if-statement, die

I have this in my code:

```
if($reuqest_id == "736" OR "015" OR "629" OR "260" OR "943" OR "365" OR "331" OR "774" OR "151" OR "452" OR "844" OR "473" OR "850" OR "173" OR "113" OR "067" OR "933" OR "259" OR "617" OR "260" OR "707" OR "256" OR "963" OR "554" OR "344" OR "173" OR "292" OR "478" OR "275") {
die("Restricted");
}
```

However, it always dies, even when the `request_id` is not matched. I thought it was because It died and it couldn't read the `}` after, but that seems odd. I looked up `OR DIE`, but it doesn't seem applicable here. I also tried this instead:

```
if($reuqest_id == "736" OR $reuqest_id == "015" OR $reuqest_id == "629" //etc..
```

But it didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried `||` instead of `OR`?

Comment: Use `||` instead of `OR` Edit: @JakeN you beat me to it

Comment: @JakeN I thought of that but I thought they were the same. Some online tutorial told me that, if this works than that was a bad tutorial.

Comment: Actually `OR` and `||` really should be the same. Even the official documentation says so.

Another way to test against a series of numbers would be to write it like:
`if (in_array($request_id, array("736","015","629", [...])){`

Comment: They're the same when doing comparisons, they're different when used in assignments. `$a = $x or $y` is different from `$a = $x || $y`

Comment: Are you sure you spelled the variable correctly? The correct spelling is `request`, not `reuqest`.

Comment: @Barmar It's not just about mistyping the variable... if that variable doesn't exist then it won't "die".
user5696934 I tried the second bit of code you posted and that doesn't "die", unless $reuqest_id = TRUE.
Anyway, check my answer, it works and you get your id list separate from your validation...

Comment: I don't see why it should make a difference. Both `||` and `OR` have lower precedence than `==`. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @Barmar because first comparison will return false:`$reuqest_id == "736"`
Then, the next comparison will be `(FALSE OR "015")`
That will return true, because of how php casts strings to boolean.
Just give it a try with `var_dump((bool) "015");` and you'll see it returns true

Comment: I'm talking about `if($reuqest_id == "736" OR $reuqest_id == "015" OR $reuqest_id == "629" //etc..`

Comment: So am I.
if you go from precedence to precedence, first thing to be evaluated is
`$reuqest_id == "736"`
After that evaluation, php doesn't continue with `$reuqest_id`, it continues the validation with whatever value was returned from the first comparison.
Because `$reuqest_id == "736"` is false, the next comparison is `false OR "015"
And that returns true, therefore it goes inside the if block. hope it's more clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that after each "OR" you need to do the whole check again:

```
$request_id === "736" || $request_id === "015" || $request_id === "629"
//and so on...
```

To avoid this, use `in_array()`.

```
$listOfIds = ["736", "015", "629", "260", "943", "365", "331", "774", "151", "452", "844", "473", "850", "173", "113", "067", "933", "259", "617", "260", "707", "256", "963", "554", "344", "173", "292", "478", "275"];

if(in_array($request_id, $listOfIds)) {
    die("Restricted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the variable with each value, like this:

```
if ($reuqest_id == "736" || $reuqest_id == "015" || $reuqest_id == "629"...) {
```

Also, check this:

- May be you spelled wrong the variable name: `$reuqest_id` seems odd, my guess it have to be `$request_id`
- We dont see how the value is asigned. If it is an integer, then some comparisions could result in FALSE: "015" is not the same as 015.